# How can we add button in custom cell?

Tags: iphone

I am working in a app and need to add button in cell by customcell.
Can any one help me for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In customcell.h
  btn1=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  btn1.frame=CGRectMake(210, 5, 100, 30);
  [self.contentView addSubview:btn1];

In cellforrowatIndexPAth
 [cell.btn1 setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 cell.btn1.tag=indexPath.row+1;
 [cell.btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1_Clicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Answer (score 0):

You add a button in Customcell so use the following code.
        First of all , you add new file with subclass of UITableViewCell and then
        Customcell.h file
               @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell 
               {
                 UIButton *customButton;
               }
    @property (nonatomic , retain) UIButton *customButton;

```
           Customcell.m
@implementation CustomCell;
           @synthesize customButton;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) 
    {
          customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phonecall.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }
         return self;
}

// set layout in subview
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{

    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;

    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;

    CGFloat boundY = contentRect.origin.y;

    CGRect frame1;

        frame1 = CGRectMake(boundsX+10, boundY+58, 19, 18);
    customButton.frame = frame1;

}

#import "CustomCell.h"
In cellForRowAtIndexPath method

// Customize the number of cells in the table view.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell= [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell.customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(callAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cell;
}
```